# Laravel 5.2 Route::Aut() I am trying to implement an additional email confirm and in last step I can´t pass a flash message when logout

Tags: laravel-5

The problem is I can´t send a flash(), reflash(), or keep() message after a user confirmed a email and finished his registration. I redirect him to /logout in laravel 5.2 in the Route:Auth().

I try to confirm user´s emails (no problem in this part) but I can´t send a message to 'welcome' view. I want log out the user after confirm his email to the user needs log in again. The unique method I find to log out is redirect('/logout') and it log out redirect to 'welcome' view, this is OK for me but I can´t send message to the view.

```
    namespace TutorialJD\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use TutorialJD\Http\Requests;
use TutorialJD\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use TutorialJD\User;
use Auth;
use Mail;
use Session;

class LogController extends Controller
{
  public function confirm($email, $confirm)
  {
    $user = new User;
    $confirm_user= $user->select()->where('email', '=', $email)->where('confirm', '=', $confirm)->get();
    if(count($confirm_user)>0){
      $active = 1;
      $confirm = str_random(100);
      $user->where('email', '=', $email)->update(['active'=> $active, 'confirm'=> $confirm]);
      Session::reflash('message', "The email: $email has been confirmed, now you can access to Dashboard");
      return redirect('/logout');
    }
    else {
      return redirect()->route('welcome');
    }
  }

}
```

These are other parts of proyect:

migration:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        //to check email confirmation
        $table->boolean('active')->default(0);
        $table->string('confirm', 100)->nullable();;
        //token to make a route to confirm email
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

AuthController:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $send['email'] = $data['email'];
    $send['name'] = $data['name'];
    $send['confirm'] = $data['confirm'];
    Mail::send('mails.register', ['send'=> $send], function($mail) use($send){
      $mail->to($send['email'], $send['name'])->subject('Please, to confirm your email, click in this link');
    });

    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'confirm' => $data['confirm'],
        'active' => 0,
    ]);

}
```

I made the LogController to confirm email, and I want do a user logout and send a flash message to welcome view like "you must log in again go to dashboard".

routes.php file:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::get('/', ['as'=> 'welcome', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    }]);
    Route::auth();
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'active']], function () {
    Route::get('/home',[
      'as'=> 'home',
      'uses' => 'HomeController@index'
    ]);
});

Route::get('auth/confirm/email/{email}/confirm/{confirm}', [
  'as'=> 'confirm',
  'uses'=> 'LogController@confirm'
  ]);
```

There is a middleware to active user too.

```
namespace TutorialJD\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;

class Active
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      if(Auth::check()){
        if(Auth::user()->active === 1){
          return $next($request);
        }
        else{
          $email= Auth::user()->email;
          $msg= session()->flash('message', "You must confirm your email to access.");
          return redirect()->route('welcome');
        }
      }
      else{
        return redirect()->route('welcome');
      }
    }
}
```

The welcome view (When in the controller I make a redirect('\logout') the Route::Auth() show the view('welcome')):

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Welcome</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    Your Application's Landing Page.
                    @if(Session::has('message'))
                      <br>
                      <strong>{{ Session::get('message') }}</strong>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

I think problem is Session file is empty after log out and message dissapear, the messages of middleware works fine but message after log out doesn´t work.

Comment: show me your routes.php ?

Comment: Did u attempt to `redirect()->withMessage("Blah")` instead?

Comment: I try but nothing happend, maybe I'm wrong in view code, I put view code in the question. I can see in Chrome console network that confirmation route call /logout and logout call welcome, but I see that cookie session changes between /logout and welcome, I think the data session is lost in that step. I can see the code of Auth/AuthController@logout that Laravel uses, and I don´t know what happend there.